# Multiple defined conditions in preprocessing

Tags: c, conditional-statements, c-preprocessor

I know that I can make some complex conditions like:

```
#if defined(A) || defined(B) || defined(C)
```

But, if I want a condition like:

```
A || (B && C)
```

Can I use parentheses or the preprocessor will ignore it and force me to write some nested condition?

I have tried:

```
#if defined(A) || (defined(B) && defined(C))
```

and it works. But just for making sure it isn't platform/compiler dependent or anything else because I couldn't find any example like that.

Thanks

Comment: I assume you mean `#if defined(A) || (defined(B) && defined(C))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C99 standard

> ## 6.10 Preprocessing directives
>
> *if-group:*
>
> **#if** *constant-expression new-line group<sub>opt</sub>*
>
> ## 6.6.3
>
> Constant expressions shall not contain assignment, increment, decrement, function-call, or comma operators, except when they are contained within a subexpression that is not evaluated

`defined(A) || (defined(B) && defined(C))` is of course a valid constant expression, so it must work

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should work because the preprocessor will check first the parentheses.